# Will the new size qualifiers (sw<n>dp) work on pre-Honeycomb devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm unsure of how the versioning of the API works in the case of [minimum-width-size-qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) introduced for Android v3.2. If I place a resource in a folder named res/values-sw600dp, will this work on pre-Honeycomb(3.2)-devices?

To rephrase: If I want to support pre-honecomb devices for my app, must I stick with the old ways of qualifying resources, like "small", "ldpi" etc?

edit: If this seems like a silly question, I ask because there *may* be some compiler magic that actually back-ports the resource files so that it works on pre 3.2-devices.

Comment: no back-ports. Android will choice the best directory for that devices. If you have not redefined it the default one will be choosed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **yes** :) You must stick with the old ways

It's explained well here: (http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

> Previous versions of the platform will ignore any resources using the new resource qualifiers. This, then, is one approach that will work:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For phones
res/layout-xlarge/main_activity.xml    # For pre-3.2 tablets
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 3.2 and up tablets
```

Basically you can use both bucket-types to ensure it works across all platforms. There are some other tricks in the above link including loading layouts programmatically. It's near the end of the post.